# C program that prints string behaves strangely

Tags: c

I just work out with this c program. But it behaves really strangely.

**This program suppose to print out `a-zA-Z0-9` randomly with length depend on the user.**

***Consider the following code.***

```
int main(){

    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

    int length , i ;
    char alph[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    do{

        printf("How many character do you want to print? >>");
        scanf("%d" , &length );

        char* user_length = (char*)malloc( length );

        printf("Strlen - %d\n" , strlen( user_length ) );

        for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){

            *( user_length + i ) = alph[ rand()%strlen( alph ) ];
        }

        printf("\nString - %s\n" , user_length );
        printf("strlen - %d\n\n" , strlen( user_length ) );

        free( user_length );

    }while( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

[image: This is the result I get. (click to view)]

The only problem is that the `user_length` does not contain "length" number of element

I can't figure out the errors. Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: Terminate your string (and don't forget the added space needed to do it.). And lose the  `printf` after your allocation; it invokes UB.

Comment: Then try responding with 1234567890 to the first question. You'll learn a whole lot of lessons from debugging that :)

Comment: I changed your question title to reflect your problem more clearly. :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a totally undefined behavior:

```
    char* user_length = (char*)malloc( length );
    printf("Strlen - %d\n" , strlen( user_length ) );
```

You just allocate an array which can be filled by any character (remaining of some data in RAM) and ask for the length of the string in this array, which is equivalent to finding the first null character ('\0') in the array.

Now that I explain that `strlen` search for the first null character, you must understand that a string always finish with `'\0'`. When you fill in your `user_length` array of character, you must put `'\0'` or simply `0` at the end in order to make it a legal string.

Also, `user_length` is a terrible name for a string, one would expect a number corresponding to some length.
With all that in mind, I would have done that :

```
int main(){

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    int length , i ;
    char alph[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    int alph_length = strlen( alph );

    do{
        printf("How many character do you want to print? >>");
        int num_scanned = scanf("%d" , &length );

        if(num_scanned!=1 || length<=0 || length>alph_length) // if the user put some shit, exit
            return -1;


        char* user_string = (char*)malloc( length+1 );

        for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
            user_string[i]  = alph[ rand()%alph_length ];
        }
        user_string[length] = '\0';

        printf("string - %s\n"
               "strlen - %zu\n\n" , user_string, strlen( user_string ) );

        free( user_string );

    }while( 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I corrected multiple other things ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
   char* user_length = malloc( length  + 1); // <-- give room for the terminating '\0', and dont cast the return of malloc
    // dont use user_length yet, it contains garbage for the moment

    printf("Strlen - %d\n" , length); 
    for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
        *( user_length + i ) = alph[ rand()%strlen( alph ) ]; // ok
    }

    user_length [length] = '\0'; // <-- null-terminate your string
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to zero-terminate the result, which makes both `strlen` and the printing of it undefined.
Terminate it properly, and remember to allocate space for the terminator (and don't cast the result of `malloc`):

```
char* user_length = malloc(length + 1);
user_length[length] = 0;
```

("User length" is a strange name for this string, by the way.)

Note that you can generate this without storing anything, though:

```
do {
    printf("How many character do you want to print? >>");
    scanf("%d" , &length );

    printf("String: ");
    for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ){
        printf("%c", alph[rand() % strlen(alph)]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} while(1);
```